# callback для .on("submit") / .on("click") и т.д

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, у меня есть callback функция, которая хранится в переменной **cb**, при клике, в случае удачного выполнения ajax (success), мне нужно вернуть эту callback (фукнцию).

Вопрос, как передать в .on("click") эту переменную, чтобы потом её вызвать в теле функции?

В обычную функцию передалось бы параметром, **testfunct(cb)**, это понятно, но как передать в функцию события **.on** - не понятно.

Пример кода:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#login-form-auth", function (e,cb) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        var url = $form.attr("action") + "?" + $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                if(data == "true") {
                    cb(); //функция callback которую надо вызвать
                } else {
                    alert("Неправильный логин или пароль!");
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, str){
                alert("Возникла ошибка: " + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: В смысле вернуть функцию? Судя по вашему коду - вам нужно просто выполнить функцию. Ну дак если эта функция определена - зачем её куда-то передавать? Просто вызывайте и все. Если прям нужно её из переменной - ну дак и объявляйте эту переменную глобально.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin Вы правы, хоть и сам уже догадался, объявил переменную глобально и всё заработало. Спасибо.